# Identify a PC with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to know or identify a PC using webpage JavaScript, HTML5 or anything else? I know that I can do it with win32 and using the MAC of the client, but I need to know if that is possible with a website.

**Note:** This question is not about ip or navigator because they can change. For example, all my clients have a dynamic ip.

Comment: You could leave a cookie. There are legal constraints on this in some countries, and the user can always clear cookies. You could use [Evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/), but it can make you very unpopular.

Comment: that is true, but the cookie is clean when the browser is closed or when this cookies are clean?

Comment: Evercookies are evil! You can't clean them even by cutting of the electricity to the whole city! :P

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Since the user is in full control of his Browser and the JavaScript engine, and also what he sends with his HTTP header, there is no bulletproof/secure way of identifying someone.

However, for the average user you can assemble a fingerprint by collecting avaibale environment data, browser behaviours and basically all other characteristics you can grab.

A very popular method is **canvas fingerprinting**, where you take advantage of the HTML5 canvas api, whose drawing results are dependend on a lot of factors (browser, os, fonts, graphics card, etc.), and use the resulting image as (part of) the individual fingerprint.

Answer (score -1):

I just readed article about **HTML5 Local storage** which You can use to save **key - value** pairs to it so next time it comes to website, just read again if there is any data stored on local storage.

User can remove that data, but I think it's not the problem. You can use it to remember state where client been last time etc, and also send it back to server.

Just storing example server generated key into client local storage, so it is not so harmful information, there you can pick up onload key to server to regocnite computer.

Here is one good link to more explained about Local Strorage
http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: I'm just asking why downvoted, please explain it to me so I can understand why not?